# Copying data into table A into table B (Is Identity == Yes)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two almost identical tables A and B in a SQL Server database.

Table A contains data and a primary key X set to `Is Identity == No`.

Table B contains no data but has primary key X set to `Is Identity == Yes` (`Identity Increment = 1, Identity Seed = 1`).

The data in primary key X increments by 1 to 100 i.e table A has 100 records, the first record is 1 and the 100th record is 100.

How do I copy the data from table A to table B in the simplest way without errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `set identity_insert tableB on` before running your `insert`

```
 set identity_insert tableB on

 insert tableB (Id, field1, field2)
 select id, field1, field2 from tablea

 set identity_insert tableB off
```

Comment: +1 but msdn mentions that [`IDENT_CURRENT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) must be lower than the ID inserted. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to enumerate the columns. On the other hand - is on the B table the identity necessary, while its taken from A?

> The data in primary key X increments by 1 to 100 i.e table A has 100 records, the first record is 1 and the 100th record is 100.

Following this rule seems the incrementation on B not being needed, while the identity is taken from table A.

Eventually consider to RESEED on B to meet the IDENT_CURRENT limitation. ( [Reseed information](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/15/sql-server-dbcc-reseed-table-identity-value-reset-table-identity/))

Comment: Yes I had to specify the fields as otherwise I was getting an error and this was not clear to me. Table B does require the identity as it allows a person to add a new record and I wanted a simple auto generation of an id. I have done it this way as I could not right click on A.X and set the Identity == Yes.

Comment: As your data will rise in time, your A to B query could possibly get you in trouble, if repeated sometime later. B can have the identity number already in use by any user record while A does not know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there are 100 rows in tableA and id are from 1 to 100 with no repetition then You can copy tableA data to tableB easily like,

```
insert tableB (field1, field2) 
select field1, field2 from tableA order by id
```

> The Id field will automatically generate as it is identity column